# Implementation of undoable arrange (SendToBack, SendBackward, ...) operations

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

I am developing a WPF designer where visual elements (rectangles, ellipses, ...) can be inserted, moved, resized and so on. Similar to a simple PowerPoint control.

All the actions should be undo-able, so all modifications to the drawing area's state are implemented as `Operation`s. An operation looks like:

```
public abstract class Operation
{
    protected Operation(string title) 
    {
        Title = title;
    }

    internal abstract void Do();
    internal abstract void Undo();
    public string Title { get; }
}
```

There are other classes used in the code below:

- The `IFormDesigner` interface is the abstraction of the desinger surface
- The `FormItem` class represents the model for one element on the designer and has (beside some other properties) an `Order` property of type `Int32` which determines the element's Z order.

I would like you to take a look on the arrange operation (*SendToBack*, *SendBackward*, *BringToFront*, *BringForward*). My first approach was, to implement a class `ArrangeOperation` with an abstract method `CalculateNewOrder` followed by 4 derived classes (`SendToBack`, `SendBackward`, `BringToFront`, `BringForward`) that implemented the abstract method. Because the method was called in contructor, I ran into ReSharper's [virtual member call in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor) warning. Actually, the warning wasn't a problem in my case, but I want to avoid it anyway because it may become a problem if the code grows...

Finally I end up with a more functional solution:

```
internal class ArrangeOperation : Operation
{
    private readonly IFormDesigner myDesigner;
    private readonly Dictionary<FormItem, int> myOrdersBefore;
    private readonly Dictionary<FormItem, int> myOrdersAfter;

    private ArrangeOperation(IFormDesigner designer, string title, Action calculateNewOrder) : base(title)
    {
        myDesigner = designer;
        myOrdersBefore = designer.FormElements.ToDictionary(e => e.Model, e => e.Model.Order);
        calculateNewOrder();
        myOrdersAfter = designer.FormElements.ToDictionary(e => e.Model, e => e.Model.Order);
    }

    internal override void Do()
    {
        ApplyOrders(myOrdersAfter);
        myDesigner.InvalidateOrders();
    }

    internal override void Undo()
    {
        ApplyOrders(myOrdersBefore);
        myDesigner.InvalidateOrders();
    }

    private static void ApplyOrders(Dictionary<FormItem, int> elementOrderDictionary)
    {
        foreach (var element in elementOrderDictionary)
            element.Key.Order = element.Value;
    }

    public static Operation CreateSendToBack(IFormDesigner designer)
    {
        var formItems = designer.Selection.Select(i => i.Model).ToArray();
        return new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationSendToBack,
            () =>
            {
                var otherItems = designer.FormElements
                    .Where(i => !formItems.Contains(i.Model))
                    .OrderBy(i => i.Model.Order)
                    .Select(f => f.Model)
                    .ToArray();

                var newOrderdItems = formItems.OrderBy(i => i.Order).ToList();
                newOrderdItems.AddRange(otherItems);
                for (int i = 0; i < newOrderdItems.Count; i++)
                    newOrderdItems[i].Order = i + 1;
            });
    }

    public static Operation CreateSendBackward(IFormDesigner designer)
    {
        var formItems = designer.Selection.Select(i => i.Model).ToArray();
        return new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationSendBackward,
            () =>
            {
                var allFormItems = designer.FormElements.Select(f => f.Model).ToArray();
                for (int i = 1; i < allFormItems.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (formItems.Contains(allFormItems[i]))
                        allFormItems.Swap(i, i - 1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < allFormItems.Length; i++)
                    allFormItems[i].Order = i + 1;
            });
    }

    public static Operation CreateBringToFront(IFormDesigner designer)
    {
        var formItems = designer.Selection.Select(i => i.Model).ToArray();
        return new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationBringToFront,
            () =>
            {
                var newOrderdItems = designer.FormElements
                    .Where(i => !formItems.Contains(i.Model))
                    .OrderBy(i => i.Model.Order)
                    .Select(f => f.Model).ToList();

                newOrderdItems.AddRange(formItems.OrderBy(i => i.Order));

                for (int i = 0; i < newOrderdItems.Count; i++)
                    newOrderdItems[i].Order = i + 1;
            });
    }

    public static Operation CreateBringForward(IFormDesigner designer)
    {
        var formItems = designer.Selection.Select(i => i.Model).ToArray();
        return new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationBringForward,
            () =>
            {
                var allFormItems = designer.FormElements.Select(f => f.Model).ToArray();
                for (int i = allFormItems.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (formItems.Contains(allFormItems[i]))
                        allFormItems.Swap(i, i + 1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < allFormItems.Length; i++)
                    allFormItems[i].Order = i + 1;
            });
    }
}
```

What do you think about the class design and the the logic for calculating the new order?

Comment: Your `CreateBringToFront` action seems pointless. Are you trying to edit the original collection?

Comment: The code creates a temporary collection with the correct order and the last for loop resets the `Order` property based on the order of the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public static Operation CreateBringToFront(IFormDesigner designer)
> {
>     var formItems = designer.Selection.Select(i => i.Model).ToArray();
>     return new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationBringToFront,
>         () =>
>         {
>             var newOrderdItems = designer.FormElements
>                 .Where(i => !formItems.Contains(i.Model))
>                 .OrderBy(i => i.Model.Order)
>                 .Select(f => f.Model).ToList();
>
>             newOrderdItems.AddRange(formItems.OrderBy(i => i.Order));
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < newOrderdItems.Count; i++)
>                 newOrderdItems[i].Order = i + 1;
>         });
> }
> ```

I like lambdas very much but putting this much code into a constructor seem like way too much. In all four cases you should encpasulate them in separate funcitons/classes and pass them to the constructor like a strategy pattern. This would make the logic easier to test (I guess) without having to be a part of an `ArrangeOperation`.

You already pass the `designer` to the constructor so there's no need for closures here. The `Action` could take one more parameter to work with later.

Comment: Hmm, I think you are right. After reflecting it again, the OOP approach (encapsulate logic in separate classes) seems to fit better even it required more boilerplate code. I am often torn between the succinct functional style and the bloated but more meaningfully OOP style. In the end, I often prefer OOP because that is the way I have learned to think... I am wonder if it just my personal preference or a general one of the human's brain :D.

Comment: @JanDotNet this is no longer functional because you have statements there. If you encapsulated everything and just do F1().F2(x => x.F3()) etc then it would be funcitonal but the `newOrderdItems.AddRange` and the for-loop break the pattern. If you had only this query `designer.FormElements` then I would say it's funcitonal but not properly ecapsulated, currently it's a mix of both. I think it's not just you. Somehow it's hard do see the flaws in your own code like my stupid dictionary for grouping. If I saw this by someone else I would screem haha ;-)

Comment: @JanDotNet I find It's ok to mix both styles but it needs be clean.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested from t3chb0t, I refactored the code to a more OOP style solution which seems to fit better :):

```
internal class ArrangeOperation : Operation
{
    private abstract class Sorter
    {
        public void Sort(IFormDesigner designer)
        {
            var selectedItems  = designer.Selection.Select(s => s.Model).ToArray();
            var sortedItems = GetSortedItems(designer, selectedItems);
            for (int i = 0; i < sortedItems.Count; i++)
                sortedItems[i].Order = i + 1;
        }
        protected abstract List<FormItem> GetSortedItems(IFormDesigner designer, FormItem[] selectedItems);
    }

    private class SendToBackSorter : Sorter
    {
        protected override List<FormItem> GetSortedItems(IFormDesigner designer, FormItem[] selectedItems)
        {
            var otherItems = designer.FormElements
                .Where(i => !selectedItems.Contains(i.Model))
                .OrderBy(i => i.Model.Order)
                .Select(f => f.Model)
                .ToArray();

            return selectedItems
                .OrderBy(i => i.Order)
                .Concat(otherItems)
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    private class SendBackwardSorter : Sorter
    {
        protected override List<FormItem> GetSortedItems(IFormDesigner designer, FormItem[] selectedItems)
        {
            var allFormItems = designer.FormElements.Select(f => f.Model).ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i < allFormItems.Count; i++)
                if (selectedItems.Contains(allFormItems[i]))
                    allFormItems.Swap(i, i - 1);
            return allFormItems;
        }
    }

    private class BringToFrontSorter : Sorter
    {
        protected override List<FormItem> GetSortedItems(IFormDesigner designer, FormItem[] selectedItems)
        {
            return designer.FormElements
                .Where(i => !selectedItems.Contains(i.Model))
                .OrderBy(i => i.Model.Order)
                .Select(f => f.Model)
                .Concat(selectedItems.OrderBy(i => i.Order))
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    private class BringForwardSorter : Sorter
    {
        protected override List<FormItem> GetSortedItems(IFormDesigner designer, FormItem[] selectedItems)
        {
            var allFormItems = designer.FormElements.Select(f => f.Model).ToList();
            for (int i = allFormItems.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                if (selectedItems.Contains(allFormItems[i]))
                    allFormItems.Swap(i, i + 1);
            return allFormItems;
        }
    }

    private readonly IFormDesigner myDesigner;
    private readonly Dictionary<FormItem, int> myOrdersBefore;
    private readonly Dictionary<FormItem, int> myOrdersAfter;

    private ArrangeOperation(IFormDesigner designer, string title, Sorter sorter) : base(title)
    {
        myDesigner = designer;
        myOrdersBefore = designer.FormElements.ToDictionary(e => e.Model, e => e.Model.Order);
        sorter.Sort(designer);
        myOrdersAfter = designer.FormElements.ToDictionary(e => e.Model, e => e.Model.Order);
    }

    internal override void Do()
    {
        ApplyOrders(myOrdersAfter);
        myDesigner.InvalidateOrders();
    }

    internal override void Undo()
    {
        ApplyOrders(myOrdersBefore);
        myDesigner.InvalidateOrders();
    }

    private static void ApplyOrders(Dictionary<FormItem, int> elementOrderDictionary)
    {
        foreach (var element in elementOrderDictionary)
            element.Key.Order = element.Value;
    }

    public static Operation CreateSendToBack(IFormDesigner designer)
        => new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationSendToBack, new SendToBackSorter());

    public static Operation CreateSendBackward(IFormDesigner designer)
        => new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationSendBackward, new SendBackwardSorter());

    public static Operation CreateBringToFront(IFormDesigner designer)
        => new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationBringToFront, new BringToFrontSorter());

    public static Operation CreateBringForward(IFormDesigner designer)
        => new ArrangeOperation(designer, Resources.OperationBringForward, new BringForwardSorter());
}
```

Comment: Looks much cleaner now and is really easy to follow but why are the sorters nested classes?

Comment: To hide them ;) Its internal stuff that should not be visible to the rest of the code.

Comment: It worked, I almost didn't find them :-P put them in a namespace like `Sorters`. Each class should have its own file (in most cases) - there are of course exceptions but this isn't one of them ;-]

Comment: The project has enough files and the classes are not used outside the `ArrangeOperation` class. Therefore I don't see a reason to put them in its own files / namespace. There is also a special "magic key" called **F12** that can  be used to find them ;P